# MVC design pattern with multiple classes in iOS

Tags: objective-c, swift, model-view-controller

I'm trying to improve the structure of my development, and stripping back to the very beginning while learning Swift. This is not language dependent though (the edit is not appropriate).

Something has been troubling me for sometime, and I hope someone can take the time to help me.

I'm making a simple game where questions are stored in a binary tree, so am creating a class for the binary tree (BinaryTree.swift).

My ViewController will take care of interactions with the interface (buttons etc.)

I need to also create the business logic for the game (which question should be returned, keeping score etc.). The logic for this type of game is trivial, but I need to understand principles before I scale up to larger projects.

**Problem**
Is it reasonable to create a class in a separate file solely for the game logic (GameLogic.swift), as I'm concerned that it is not a reasonable way to structure this app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In all honesty, it is up to the developer to choose how they structure their data. The MVC, or Model View Controller model is still alive and well but I choose not to use it. Without a who lot of information on what exactly would go into `GameLogic.swift`, I would say go ahead and try it. Maybe another developer with more experience than me can give you another idea!

Comment: The thing is, it will work but I really want to get it to work as you'd expect a competent developer to do it. Gamelogic.swift would (for example) keep track of score, perhaps have a timer for how long the player has been thinking about an answer....that type of thing.

Comment: Totally understand! Are you a new developer (1-5 months in)?

Comment: Yes, well just at the point where things need to be maintainable.

Comment: From personal experience, I found that I did not need to worry about my data structures so much when I first started developing because I learned new material and constantly (and still do) change the way I set things up - just a personal preference. Hope someone else who has more experience can guide you, also!!